# Logic dilemma about a synchronization process

Tags: mysql, logic

I maintain and develop a web application that's used online but also offline.
(Offline meaning installed on 30 something laptops that use MySQL for database)

For the people who uses the offline version, I have a synchronization system in place.
This synchronization exchanges newly updated info from the live version to the offline version and vice versa.

I have a recurrent problem, that sometimes the sync works and sometimes not.
(Often is about duplicate key already exists.)

I have an **appointment table** that has an **ID (primary key)**.
How would you determine that an appointment created offline is the same that one that already exists online and vice versa also?
That exact appointment doesn't have the same id offline and online.

Hope is clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

Why the offline and the online IDs are different? The sync system doesn't copy the same row with all the same informations from/to the online database?

Anyway you need to implement a logic to create the offline IDs in a way that, at least a part of it, is uniquely bindable to an offline station/user.

For example: if you are offline and want to save a new appointment, build an ID crafted like this:

```
"useridWhoCreatedTheAppointment + UserLocalCounter"
```

or

```
"useridWhoCreatedTheAppointment + datetimeToString(ddMMyyHHmmssSSS)"
```

In this way you won't have any duplicate key.